# SAP Spartacus Gigya: Log in successful but the frontend is not updated

Tags: spartacus-storefront, gigya

In the SAP Spartacus B2B storefront, we are using Gigya to do the log in process. Everything works and we can enter the account details to log in.

But after logging in, while we can see the account details in the "Network" panel, the frontend is not updated and the user is stuck in the log in page. There's a short loading animation shows up, but nothing else happens.

I have checked if there's any possibility for me to edit that log in panel, but it seems it is generated via the JS files from Gigya so probably that's not a good idea.

I have also tried with wrong account details. It is recognized and the panel shows "Invalid login or password". So the account verification function works.

Is there any special setup required to update the frontend after the user login successfully with Gigya in Spartacus Storefront? I am using Spartacus 6.5 btw.

Comment: Are you using cdc screensets or the loginUserWithoutScreenSet function in CdcJsService?

Comment: @MehmetS I am using CDC screensets.

Comment: After the accounts.login request sent to CDC on the network in developer tools, a request is made to the hybris token service and can you successfully get the access_token information?

In other words, the following requests should be made respectively;
1. accounts.login
2. token

Comment: @MehmetS accounts.login is made, but token is not. The token is received btw.

Comment: First, it needs to go to the accounts.login service on the cdc side and give the id_token information from there to the auth token service of hybris. In the case you mentioned, the user logged in to CDC, but Hybris is not aware of this. That's why you can't see any changes in the frontend.

Comment: So, the order should be as follows: first, it will go to cdc's accounts.login service and if the login is successful, it will go to the loginWithCustomCdcFlow method in the CdcAuthService. If there is no problem, the loadTokenUsingCustomFlow method in CdcUserAuthenticationTokenService should work and information such as UID, UIDSignature, idToken coming from the accounts.login service will go to the hybris auth token service.

Comment: You can try to determine where the problem is by debugging the onLoginEventHandler method in CdcJsService. Maybe the response after the cdc login process says response?.context?.skipOccAuth true, so it cannot start the login process on the hybris side. Just an idea, you can check this with debug.